# Google Maps Physical not render-able below a certain scale?

Tags: qgis, openlayers, google-maps

Having some troubles opening Google Maps Physical layer in QGIS using OpenLayers. I cannot seem to have the layer load below a scale of 1:29,802.

Is this normal?

My projection is set to 3857 and my QGIS version is 2.18.9.

Comment: Which part of the world are you looking at?

Comment: I am looking at Canberra, ACT, Australia. Particularly the suburb of 'Hall'. I can load the physical map at very small scales in Google Maps, but I can't seem to do the same in QGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenLayers plugin has many caveats.

Try the QuickMapServices plugin instead. You will find the `Google Physical` Layer named `Google Terrain`.

If you use the plugin for the first time, you have to run `Web -> QuickMapServices -> Settings`, `More services` tab, `Get contributed pack` button to get the full list of providers.